# Passing PHP time through to JS

Tags: javascript, php, json, canvasjs

I have been trying to plot some data from a database using canvasJS. I currently have it so it takes my data, encodes it as json and passes it back where it is plotted on a line graph and this works fine but it simply uses numerical values of 0, 1 , 2 , 3 ... for the x values.

Now I would like to take the times I also have in the database and use these as x values. When I simply take them and stick them in the json encode they are added as strings in the format (hh:mm:ss)

When I use `strtotime($row['time'])` they are converted to timestamps and plotted but these make no sense. How can I convert them back to javascript times that make more sense when plotted?

here is the code that does the ajax call:

```
  $.post( "display_ajax.php", { hour: $("#slider-range").slider("values",0)+":"+$("#slider-range").slider("values",1)}, function( datax ) {

console.log(datax);
  dataPoints = datax;
        dataSeries.dataPoints = dataPoints;
     data.push(dataSeries); 
     console.log(dataPoints);

  draw_chart ();



  },"json");
```

where the data being passed is two values taken from a jquery slider that correspond to a time range.

Comment: What does the PHP timestamp look like and what does the Javascript timestamp look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Javascript timestamps include milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

> Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch)

In your PHP, when you do `strtotime($row['time'])` you need to multiply by 1000 as `strtotime` returns the number of seconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC up to the date specified.

```
$js_time = strtotime($row['time']) * 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks, then how do I convert back in order for the graph to plot? Currently I'm just taking the json data and pushing it into the dataPoints array for the chart to plot.

Comment: What do you mean convert back? Have a look at http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/date-time-axis/ for how to display dates on the x-axis of CanvasJS

Comment: Specifically, have a look at the `axisX:{ valueFormatString: "YYYY-MM-DD" }` option

Comment: And also the "Date time example using TimeStamps" example, as that's the date format we're generating in PHP. (Note how in the example all the x values end in 0000 for 0 milliseconds)